# Beginner Regular Expressions Java

Tags: java, regex, expression

I'm wanting to write a Regular Expression that will match to one of several variations / common uses of a name.

I need to accept a user input, & then validate that the input matches one of the listed variations. If there is a match, I need to output that there was match, if not I should output that the input wasn't a match.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExMyName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Name: Daimon");
        System.out.println("Common Usages: Daimon, Daimo, Dai, daimon, daimo, DAIMON");
        System.out.println("Enter any of the variations listed only: ");

        //*** HELP REQUIRED WITH PATTERN BELOW - pat
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile();
        Matcher match = pat.matcher(scan.nextLine());


        //***HELP REQUIRED WITH FIND BELOW
        if (match.find()){
            System.out.println("*** You entered a valid name ***");
        }else{
            System.out.println("*** You entered an invalid name ***");
        }




    }
}
```

I would like some help constructing the pattern or receiving suggestions for alternative methods that would accomplish the same thing.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't my name be "(╯°□°)╯"? Are you trying to abstract this to a generic name validator or only validate variations of one specific name?

Comment: Read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).  By the way, `match.find()` will find a match as long as any part of the string matches the pattern.  If you want to make sure the entire string matches with no extra stuff on the left or right, use `match.matches()`.

Comment: I would use a `Set` here to check the input against the allowed list

Comment: Thanks for the replies!
I'm trying to validate one single name, but information regarding best practice so as to abstract this to a generic name validator would surely be of interest if it can be provided?

Comment: Oh right, OK - I wasn't sure how this all worked. I will review the posts & update as necessary. Thanks for info.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern will match any of the strings `Daimon`, `Daimo`, `Dai`, `daimon`, `daimo`, `DAIMON`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([dD]aimon?|DAIMON|Dai)$");
```

Or a slightly more generous pattern would look something like this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^dai(mon?)?$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: The generous pattern would also match `dAiMon`, etc. (This comment is meant to be informative)

Comment: @nhahtdh True. That's why a called it 'more generous'. If OP really needed to limit the input to *only* those strings specified in the list, the first pattern would suffice.

Comment: Thanks, much obliged!
So if I have the pattern set as one above, how would I use this with the if statement i.e. what method should I call, & what parameter should be passed - is match.find(ARGUMENT) the right option?

Comment: @user2904978 `match.find()` should be fine by itself.

Comment: @user2904978 See also this excellent [regex explainer](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5Edai%28mon%3F%29%3F%24)

Comment: Thank You for the link - very handy!

Answer (score 2):

I would not use regular expression for the case you described i would rather store the possible variations of the name e.g. in a List would validate the input just with a simple contains.

```
List<String> daimons = Arrays.asList("Daimon", "Daimo", "Dai", "daimon", "daimo", "DAIMON");
```

I don't see really the power of the regex for your example. If i would not see your solution probably my would be something similar:

public class RegExMyName {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<String> daimons = Arrays.asList("Daimon", "Daimo", "Dai", "daimon", "daimo", "DAIMON");
    StringBuilder diamonCommonUsage = new StringBuilder();
    for(String daimonVariations : daimons) {
      diamonCommonUsage.append(daimonVariations);
      diamonCommonUsage.append(", "); //+ remove the last ","
    }        

    System.out.println("Name: Daimon");
    System.out.println("Common Usages: " + diamonCommonUsage.toString());
    System.out.println("Enter any of the variations listed only: ");

    if (match.find(daimons.contains(scan.nextLine()))){
        System.out.println("*** You entered a valid name ***");
    }else{
        System.out.println("*** You entered an invalid name ***");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I am having to test using RegEx.

Comment: Hehe it than changes everything! But yeah you are welcome. :)